# Slow SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server-2012, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

First let me start off by saying I am in no way a DB expert. I know enough to be dangerous, but I am primarily a c# developer. I have a query off a view that is slow, but I am having problems figuring out the root cause. I have attached the query plan, hoping I can get some insight here.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1GT43J8e

Here is the view info as well:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ReSyncAdwords]
WITH schemabinding
AS
  SELECT dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc - dervtable.Bid AS Expr1,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.webid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.adgroupid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.keywordid,
         dervtable.SKU,
         dervtable.Bid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.campaginid
  FROM   dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WebSkuLookup
                      ON dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.webid = dbo.WebSkuLookup.webid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SKU,
                                 Bid,
                                 Channel,
                                 DTStamp,
                                 campaginid
                          FROM   dbo.BidHistory AS ph1
                          WHERE  ( DTStamp = (SELECT MAX(DTStamp) AS Expr1
                                              FROM   dbo.BidHistory AS ph2
                                              WHERE  ( campaginid = ph1.campaginid )
                                                     AND ( ph1.SKU = SKU )) )) AS dervtable
                      ON dbo.WebSkuLookup.sku = dervtable.SKU
                         AND dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.campaginid = dervtable.campaginid
  WHERE  ( dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc - dervtable.Bid <> 0 )

GO
```

Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE  ( dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc - dervtable.Bid <> 0 )` converts your left joins back to inner joins BTW

Comment: Oh, interesting. I think I understand why. Just to confirm, since NULLs would get omitted I might as well be doing an inner join. Correct?

Comment: yes. Though the plan shows the optimiser just treats them as inner joins anyway.

Comment: Can you better define what "slow" means and how quickly you need the query to complete? If the query finishes at all it would be very helpful to provide an actual plan posted to Paste The Plan.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the comment. But it seems the answer below has fixed this query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why all the ( ) and long names?
Why mixed lowerecase camel case on table names?

Just basic cleanup

```
  SELECT dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc - dervtable.Bid AS Expr1,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.webid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.adgroupid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.keywordid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.campaginid,
         dervtable.SKU,
         dervtable.Bid
  FROM   dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WebSkuLookup
                      ON dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.webid = dbo.WebSkuLookup.webid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SKU, campaginid, Bid
                          FROM   dbo.BidHistory AS ph1
                          WHERE  DTStamp = ( SELECT MAX(DTStamp) AS Expr1
                                             FROM   dbo.BidHistory AS ph2
                                             WHERE  ph1.campaginid = ph2.campaginid
                                             AND    ph1.SKU = ph2.SKU )
                        ) AS dervtable
                      ON dbo.WebSkuLookup.sku = dervtable.SKU
                     AND dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.campaginid = dervtable.campaginid
                     AND dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc <> dervtable.Bid
```

row_number()

```
  SELECT dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc - dervtable.Bid AS Expr1,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.webid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.adgroupid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.keywordid,
         dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.campaginid,
         dervtable.SKU,
         dervtable.Bid
  FROM   dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WebSkuLookup
                      ON dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.webid = dbo.WebSkuLookup.webid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SKU, campaginid, Bid 
                               , row_number over (partition by SKU, campaginid order by DTStamp desc) as rn
                          FROM   dbo.BidHistory AS ph1
                        ) AS dervtable
                      ON dbo.WebSkuLookup.sku = dervtable.SKU 
                     AND dervtable.rn = 1
                     AND dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.campaginid = dervtable.campaginid
                     AND dbo.currentadwordsmaxbid.maxcpc <> dervtable.Bid
```